# How to use Spark Sql to do recursive query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use spark sql to recursively query over hierarchal dataset and identifying the parent root of the all the nested children.

I've tried using self-join but it only works for 1 level.

Any ideas or pointers ?

Thanks

Comment: Other than building your queries on top of iterative joins you don't. You can take a look at [graphframes](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes) but these are fairly limited.

Comment: @zero323 - the problem with joins is that there is no way to know the depth of the joins. It could be 1-level, 2-level or 3-level deep /interations

Comment: I am fully aware of that but this is something you'll have to deal one way or another. If you need fine grained control over the execution you can drop to the GraphX API but if you want high level approach this pretty much the only option.

Comment: Some preprocessing may help the querying...You can check if having nested set model will suit your purposes... http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Graphx-based solution to perform a recursive query (parent/child or hierarchical queries) .  This is a functionality provided by many databases called Recursive Common Table Expressions (CTE) or Connect by SQL Clause

See this article for more information: https://www.qubole.com/blog/processing-hierarchical-data-using-spark-graphx-pregel-api/