# filling missing combination in a table

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

input:

```
item   loc   month    year   qty
 A     DEL    5        2020   12
 A     DEL    6        2020   14
 A     DEL    8        2020   16
 A     DEL    9        2020   17
```

output:

```
item   loc   month    year   qty
 A     DEL    5        2020   12
 A     DEL    6        2020   14
 A     DEL    7        2020   26
 A     DEL    8        2020   16
 A     DEL    9        2020   17
 A     DEL    10       2020   33
```

description:

I don't have month 7 in my input. So for calculating month 7 i do sum of previous two months quantity.

for example for month 7 output will be 12(from month 5)+14(from month 6)=26

So its like whenever any month will be missing i should fill that month with this logic.

Comment: You have month 6 in the input.  Do you mean 7?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry.......yes i mean 7

Comment: So, if months 7 and 8 are missing, we'd calculate month 7 from months 5 and 6 and then month 8 from month 6 and the calculated month 7 figure?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes

Comment: You want an iterative process then. SQL is not made for iterations. It is best to use a programming language instead. If you want to use SQL, then you need a recursive query. They don't seem to be directly available in Spark. If you must do this in SQL, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904807/how-to-use-spark-sql-to-do-recursive-query.

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: @GordonLinoff any thought on this qn?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a script which is two step process but it only considers missing month between the values and not boundary values i.e. it wont assume 10 is missing as it is a boundary value.

1st Step: Insert the misisng month with NULL for all other columns.

```
 INSERT INTO TEST_MISSING(MONTH)
 select min_a - 1 + level
     from ( select min(MONTH) min_a
                 , max(MONTH) max_a
              from TEST_MISSING
          )
  connect by level <= max_a - min_a + 1
    minus
   select MONTH
     from TEST_MISSING;
```

2nd Step: Populate the values of other columns using lag with values from rows about it.

and then using Window function calculate the quantity value.

```
SELECT NVL(ITEM, NEW_ITEM) ITEM, 
     NVL(LOC, NEW_LOC) LOC, 
     MONTH, NVL(YEAR, NEW_YEAR) YEAR,
     CASE WHEN QTY IS NULL THEN SUM(NVL(QTY, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY NEW_ITEM ORDER BY MONTH ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) ELSE QTY END AS QTY
     FROM (
     SELECT A.*, 
     nvl(item,CASE WHEN ITEM IS NULL THEN (LAG(ITEM) OVER(ORDER BY MONTH)) END) NEW_ITEM,
     nvl(LOC,CASE WHEN LOC IS NULL THEN (LAG(LOC) OVER(ORDER BY MONTH)) END) NEW_LOC,
     nvl(YEAR,CASE WHEN YEAR IS NULL THEN (LAG(YEAR) OVER(ORDER BY MONTH)) END) NEW_YEAR
     FROM TEST_MISSING A) 
     X 
     ORDER BY MONTH;
```

Comment: I didn’t got this.

Comment: Can you make it simple

Comment: What do you meant by simple, you are having trouble understanding the logic or you want to do it in single step ?

Comment: You know spark?

Comment: I am also not able to understand your solution.......if you have some simple solution something like I can refer me input table itself and then get output from it

Comment: Sorry I cant make it any simpler, maybe someone else can help on this.

Comment: What is this connect by?

Comment: Can you help me by writing the description of the solution that you have given.   May be something like Seudo code thanks in advance